# How to Fix: requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages error on symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Hie I get the following error when trying create a symfony project. This has been working well until I tried to start another project. Help please.

```
$ php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition BookSite

Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.6.3)
  - Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.6.3)
    Loading from cache

Created project in BookSite
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1

    - sensio/distribution-bundle v3.0.12 requires sensiolabs/security-checker ~2.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.0].
    - sensio/distribution-bundle v3.0.13 requires sensiolabs/security-checker ~2.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.0].
    - sensio/distribution-bundle v3.0.14 requires sensiolabs/security-checker ~2.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.0].
    - sensio/distribution-bundle v3.0.15 requires sensiolabs/security-checker ~2.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.0].
    - sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for sensio/distribution-bundle ~3.0.12 -> satisfiable by sensio/distribution-bundle[v3.0.12, v3.0.13, v3.0.14, v3.0.15].
```

Comment: You need curl, for ubuntu's `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`, windows idk :/ ;p

Comment: i used curl to instal composer: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php then i ran the create project command

Comment: You have to try `php -i` or `phpinfo()` and if installed `php-curl` then try enable `curl` extension in `php.ini`

Answer (score 3):

Install PHP extension curl

apt-get install php5-curl

Answer (score 0):

Install php extension:

### sudo apt install php7.0-curl